# Is there any way to make never() + startsWith() matcher report what matched?

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I've got this:

```
verify(logger, never()).info(startsWith("Created content from "));
```

The error message is this:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked: 
logger.info(
    startsWith("Created content from ")
);
```

Because I'm using `startsWith`, it would be really helpful to see what the full string was to be able to debug this failure.  Is there any way to get that String?

Comment: Do you have a lot of logged messages that start with `"Created content from "`?

Comment: Not sure *exactly* what/why you're asking.  The answer to that question is it depends on how long the program runs.  Every time a certain object is created that message gets logged.  It can occur multiple times in one test.  I'd say about 3 might be average.

Comment: Nevermind. Doesn't Mockito log `"But invoked here: ..."` with the corresponding stack trace element? I'm guessing you want the rest of the message.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes but unfortunately that's not very useful in this case.  A lot of paths lead to this one place and how it got there is not very informative.  The key to debugging in this situation is knowing what got passed in, not the stack trace.

Comment: I was going to suggest an `ArgumentCaptor`, but the check for `never()` happens before the `ArgumentCaptor` has a chance to receive the argument.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think that you can do this is to write your own matcher. You could stick a method in your own utility class that returns a matcher, for example...

```
public class CustomMatchers {
    public static String capturingStartsWith(final String expected) {
        return Mockito.argThat(new TypeSafeMatcher<String>() {

            private String actual;

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("String that starts with: ");
                description.appendValue(expected);
                description.appendText(" actual: ");
                description.appendValue(actual);
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(String actual) {
                this.actual = actual;
                return actual.startsWith(expected);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then your test...

```
import static CustomMatchers.*;
...
@Test
public void shouldNotDoWhatItDoesNow() {
    classUnderTest.doStuff();

    verify(logger, never()).info(capturingStartsWith("Created content from"));
}
```

This will give you output like this...

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked: 
logger.info(
    Start that starts with: "Created content from" actual: "Created content from [WIBBLE]"
);
Never wanted here:
-> at  CustomStartsWithTest.shouldNotDoWhatItDoesNow(CustomStartsWithTest.java:28)
But invoked here:
-> at CustomStartsWith.doStuff(CustomStartsWith.java:12)
```

(It might be more elegant to not wrap the type safe matcher in the"argThat" within the helper method and return a Matcher)

I am not aware of any free libraries that have extra matchers like this. There might be a more clever way of hacking Mockito to do this for you...